# Django: Invalid block tag on line 14: 'endblock', expected 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: python, django

I am a new python learner and I am currently going through Chapter 19 of Python Crash Course edition and I am encountering this problem with topics.html file

> Django: Invalid block tag on line 14: 'endblock', expected 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

My topics.html file looks like this:

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <p>Topics</p>
    <ul>
      {% for topic in topics %}
    <li>
      <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a>
    <li>
      {% empty %}
    </ul>
  <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:new_topic' %}">Add a new topic</a>

{% endblock content %}
```

The Line 14 which it was referring to was this:

```
{% endblock content %}
```

I searched for similar tickets like this and I thought it was the spacing in that line.  I edited it and I still get the same issue.  I checked the rest of the file and it seems to follow the proper spacing of the { and %.

Please help me figure this one out.  Would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You should end your for loop after empty tag. Check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty) for usage `for..empty` tags

Comment: It worked!  Thanks!  I missed that one out.  Really appreciate it